# Nature style files and figures

Tags: graphics, floats, templates

I downloaded a Nature style file from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nature/) but I don't see any images when I build my figures. Do you know if this is intentional or if I've done something wrong?

If you've drafted a LaTeX paper for any Nature journal, I'd love your advice!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting lines 126--129 of `nature.cls`:

```
%% The new figure environment defers printing of all figure captions
%% until the end of the document and prints them in sans serif font.
%% The \includegraphics command is ignored since Nature wants figures
%% as separate files.
```

Comment: Aha, so the answer to the OP's question is "intentional"!

Answer (score 10):

Do you use `\includegraphics` for your pictures? If so, it seems that `nature.cls` will ignore them intentionally- from the last few lines:

```
%% ignore all \includegraphics commands in the document
\AtBeginDocument{\let\includegraphics\NAT@ignore}

\newcommand{\NAT@ignore}[2][]{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, open the `nature.cls` file and comment the last two lines.

```
%\AtBeginDocument{\let\includegraphics\NAT@ignore}
%\newcommand{\NAT@ignore}[2][]{}
```

It seems to work now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can add syntax highlighting of code by selecting the code and clicking the button marked `{}`.

Comment: unable to edit the nature.cls file. Access denied. How to solve the issue. Is there any other way to insert images in latex apart from graphicx module?