# Nature include graphics and table inside main body of text

Tags: tables, graphics, templates, includegraphics

This question follows off  [Nature include graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362195/nature-include-graphics). As posted there by commenter, Nature encourages the inclusion of figures (and tables) into the main body of text for initial submissions (which most submissions tend to be). Separate upload of figures is allowed, but the formatting for initial submissions is very open, and the inclusion of figures is recommended for ease of review. How do I do this while calling nature.cls? The solution in [Nature style files and figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/nature-style-files-and-figures) is not clear: I don't also particularly want to modify the cls file which is packaged for my linux distribution but would rather modify the call in the LaTeX file. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please consider to accept the provided answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it is off topic

Comment: I think it's on topic, it asks how to change the behavior of the `nature.cls` class on CTAN. If this is a valid approach to submit a paper to the Nature journal is not entirely clear, but that does not make the question off-topic I think.

Answer (score 2):

Does *Nature* provide class/package files for its publications? The `nature.cls` on CTAN was created by someone with no *Nature* affiliation trying to implement their Word template in LaTeX.

The following MWE does something to meet your desires.

```
% natureprob.tex  SE 562912
\documentclass{nature}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\let\keepcation\caption
\let\keepincludegraphics\includegraphics

\begin{document}

\renewenvironment{figure}{\let\caption\keepcation}{}

\let\caption\keepcation
\let\includegraphics\keepincludegraphics

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}
\centering
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Included graphic}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
TABULATION
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

`nature.cls` changes the definitions of the `caption`, `\includegraphics` and `figure` environments. The MWE keeps the old definitions and than restores them after `nature.cls` has done its work. I must admit that the result does not look particularly good.

I think that it would good if *Nature* produced its own LaTeX class and package files that produced the results it wanted. Does *Nature* really rely on Word?

Comment: I wonder if there is an error: I get "! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float." Yes, it would be nice for Nature to provide LaTex templates, no question.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 \caption
             {A figure}
?  
I get the errors for both Lines 21 and 27, where the calls to captions are.